# Finding specific values in an array

Tags: arrays, r, iterator, rstudio

I am relatively new to R programming. I am writing a code that generates an array of numbers:

```
[1] 0.5077399,  0.4388107, 0.3858783, 0.3462711, 0.3170844, 0.2954411, 0.2789464, 0.2658839,

[9] 0.2551246, 0.2459498
```

*Note: I manually separated the values by commas for ease on the eyes* :)

I want to pick the first 3 numbers from this array that are below `0.3 - [0.2954411, 0.2658839, 0.2551246]`. In addition to picking these values, I want to generate the numbers that represents where those three values exist within the array. In this case, I want the code to give me [6,7,8].

How would I write code to do this?

I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: `?which` would be useful

Comment: Also, that is a "vector" in R terminology, not an array (which in R is typically a multi-dimensional structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a similar simulated set,

```
y <- c(2, 4,6, 8)
ind <- which(y < 6) ## for finding indices 1 and 2
val <- y[y<6]       ## for picking values  2 and 4
```

Comment: Thank's a million! You just made my day ^_^